# netplan apply/try/generate ends with ERROR

Tags: ubuntu, netplan

We have cloud infrastructure based on VMWare with Windows and Linux VMs. After last reboot 4 of the Ubuntu (3 Ubuntu 20.04 and one Ubuntu 16.04) servers did not start network interface.
With `lshw -class network` I see correct network interface listed. There is no DHCP in the network, all servers use static IP's.
After reboot in `networkctl` OPERATIONAL column for the specific interface is OFF.
Only way to get network working is with following IP command sequence, but after reboot everything is gone:

```
$ip link set <link_name> up
$ip addr add <server-ip>/24 dev <link_name>
$ip route add default via <gateway> dev <link_name>
```

Looks like the problem is with netplan. I have netplan config, that is deployed together with server, when created from template and it works great on all the other Ubuntu servers in this infrastructure except those 4 servers. Also it worked on those servers until this weeks reboot (we update and reboot once a month usually) Config looks like this:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    <link_name>:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses:
        - <server_ip>/24
      gateway4: <gateway>
      nameservers:
        search:
          - <domain>
        addresses:
          - <dns_1>
          - <dns_2>
```

But when trying to `netplan apply` , `netplan generate` or `netplan try`, it returns strange ERROR, I cant find anything about in the internet.( I substituted my gateway IP with <correct_gateway> and the other IP in this operations with <some_random_ip> for security purposes)

```
ERROR:src/parse.c:1120:handle_gateway4: assertion failed (scalar(node) == cur_netdef->gateway4): ("<correct_gateway>" == "<some_random_ip>")
Bail out! ERROR:src/parse.c:1120:handle_gateway4: assertion failed (scalar(node) == cur_netdef->gateway4): ("<correct_gateway>" == "<some_random_ip>")
```

If I add some indentation mistake in *.yaml config file it returns normal Error message that points to this mistake.

I tried to reinstall netplan.io without any luck and don't have an idea what to try next.

Comment: Hi, can you show us the format of ip you used in gw or other ? Just replaces numbers by fakes one, like 1 :)
Maybe, check updates on your server, meybe there's a patched version ; your netplan file seams good.
Last possibility : your file contains strange character, try deleting it and copy/paste content from a working one

Comment: I checked mine, our dash are indented directly under the category. For addresses, the dash in under the 'a' of addresses ; but not sure it can interfer

Comment: @Martin IP is standard ipv4 : 111.111.111.111/24 for IP and 111.111.111.111 for gw.

Comment: And I don't think that dashes is an issue, as moving them don't change anything. I also rewrote the file with square brackets ([ ]) like in the netplan examples, but still the same error.
 Will try to copy file from working machine and check what going on..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, found solution.

The problem was depreciated `gateway4` tag in configuration file.

What was `gateway4: <gateway>` , now is:

```
      routes:
      - to: default
        via: <gateway>
        metric: 100
```